# Totally Clear Durable Function cached data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable function which is started using a queue

```
public async Task RunOrchestratorAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("my-queue", Connection = "event-bus-connection")] string queueItem,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(queueItem);
            await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestratorFunction", dto);
        }
```

When I start the function it seems to be remembering old messages that were on the queue which are no longer there now

I don't want the function to be run using old queue messages that have somehow been saved

```
my-queue-36c2577b-91b6-4dd1-aae3-318507509fd6-Receiver: ReceiveBatchAsync start. MessageCount = 1
```

How can I clear this history?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the queues, blob containers and tables. Then restart your app, they will be re-created.

Comment: How can I remove just the data for this function and nothing else? Nothing shows in visual studio code

Comment: In VS Code, this is one way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59037143/1658906